# extract strings between two strings in python using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string

> "<>THIS is the place to stay at when visiting the historical area of
>   Seattle.
>
> Your right on the water front near the ferry's and great sea food
>   hotel.
>
> The breakfast was great.  <>"

Above is my sample text. I want to print the strings fall in between `<>` & `<>`. I want my output to be free of new line character `\n`, like this:

> THIS is the place to stay at when visiting the historical area of
>   Seattle. Your right on the water front near the ferry's and great sea
>   food hotel.The breakfast was great.

I have tried the following piece of code:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\<>(.+?)\<>',re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
text = """<>THIS is the place to stay at when visiting the historical area of Seattle.

Your right on the water front near the ferry's and great sea food hotel.

The breakfast was great.
<>"""
results = pattern.findall(text)
print results
```

But I am getting results like this :

```
["THIS is the place to stay at when visiting the historical area of Seattle.\n\nYour right on the water front near the ferry's and great sea food hotel.\n\nThe breakfast was great.\n"]
```

But I don't want any new line characters in my resulting string.

Comment: Just use `.replace("\n", "")` on each found match. See https://ideone.com/2i5Rl8

Comment: Both answers ideas look similar, but the question is not clear in if either the list shall remain (then Wiktors answer is the best match) or there shall be one string at the end, then UpZone's answer solves that. In any case both answers work I guess ;-)

Comment: but i dont want any extra piece of code to slow down the processing.. Can i combine it with the        **pattern = re.compile(r'\<>(.+?)\<>',re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.replace("\n", "")` on each found match (use comprehension) to replace any newline with an empty string.

See the [demo](https://ideone.com/2i5Rl8):

```
results = [x.replace("\n", "") for x in pattern.findall(text)]
# => ["THIS is the place to stay at when visiting the historical area of Seattle.Your right on the water front near the ferry's and great sea food hotel.The breakfast was great."]
```

Comment: but i dont want any extra piece of code to slow down the processing.. Can i combine it with the        **pattern = re.compile(r'\<>(.+?)\<>',re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)**

Comment: @albinantony: no, you cannot *match* *discontinuous* text within *one* match operation.

Comment: I have written a general [article about extracting strings between two strings with regex](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/extracting-text-two-strings-regular-expressions), too, feel free to read if you have a problem approaching your current similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

just replace those characters you don't want

e.g.

```
result_without_newline = str(result).replace('\n', '')
```

hope this helps :)